# Cell doesn't show up properly in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using TableView to implement it on ViewController. The problem that I'm facing is the number of cells. Currently the cells supposed to return 2 rows but it only show one row.

What I want to achieve

[image]

Storyboard - You can ignore the rest of the components except the tableview

[image]

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var locationTableView: UITableView!

    let locationArray = ["Current Location", "Where to"]
    let picArray = ["currentPic.png", "whereTo.png"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        locationTableView.delegate = self
      }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return locationArray.count
    }


     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GetLocation", for: indexPath)

     let location = locationArray[indexPath.row]
     let pic = picArray[indexPath.row]
        print(location)
        if let locationCell = cell as? GetLocationTableViewCell {
            locationCell.locationTitle.text = location
            locationCell.iconImage.image = pic
        }

     return cell

     }
}
```

GetLocationTableViewCell.swift

```
    import UIKit

    class GetLocationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


        @IBOutlet var iconImage: UIImageView!

        @IBOutlet var locationTitle: UILabel!

        override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
            super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

    }
```

The outcome is really weird

**On Simulator**

[image]

**On my iphone**

[image]

The number of rows differ on both platforms. What did I do wrong? Is it because of constraints?

Comment: Do you have a table view inside a table view cell? Why?

Comment: Clearly this seems constraints related issue, How's your constraints are passed !

Answer (score 0):

Here is problem  `locationArray[indexPath.section] , picArray[indexPath.section]` your section is return 0 so you get two times display "Current Location" you need to use `indexPath.row`

Try this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GetLocation", for: indexPath)

     let location = locationArray[indexPath.row]
     let pic = picArray[indexPath.row]
        print(location)
        if let locationCell = cell as? GetLocationTableViewCell {
            locationCell.locationTitle.text = location
            locationCell.iconImage.image = pic
        }

     return cell

     }
```

Comment: I updated the questions already, I used your method which changing section to row, it works but the number of row is still unpredictable on both platforms, is it because of constraints?

Comment: yes , you need to give proper height constraint of your view

Comment: use auto layout

Comment: Are you talking about the cell constraints?

Comment: Or do I need to make the height of the tableview itself fixed?

Comment: you need to give height of the tableview itself fixed

Answer (score 0):

Change your table delegate method like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GetLocation", for: indexPath)

     let location = locationArray[indexPath.section]
     let pic = picArray[indexPath.row]//replace this line
        print(location)
        if let locationCell = cell as? GetLocationTableViewCell {
            locationCell.locationTitle.text = location
            locationCell.iconImage.image = pic
        }

     return cell

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like  Bellow. You can write array like

```
 let locationArray = [
    ["textName":"Current Location", "imageName":"currentPic"],
    ["textName":"Where to", "imageName":"whereTo"]
]
```

Table view protocol method look like

```
     override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
       return 1
  }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

      return locationArray.count
   }


  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath) CustomCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = locationArray[indexPath.row]["textName"]
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: locationArray[indexPath.row]["imageName"]!)

      return cell
     }
```

Comment: If you want add in section just write indexPath.section. there no need two array maintain.

Answer (score 0):

> Replace method Following thing in `cellRowAtPath`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GetLocation", for: indexPath)

     let location = locationArray[indexPath.row]
     let pic = picArray[indexPath.row]
        print(location)
        if let locationCell = cell as? GetLocationTableViewCell {
            locationCell.locationTitle.text = location
            locationCell.iconImage.image = pic
        }

     return cell

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 102 //Give cell height
}
```

Comment: I used this method already, but it is unpredictable. You can take a look at the updated questions

Comment: Make sure you give locationTableView.dataSource = self

Answer (score 0):

As Per your problem i suggest you to manage constraints that your are applying to tableview and Cell. Here i have provided instruction to follow to get solution. Please Manage to follow same instruction on your project Hope this will solve your problem.

**1. Manage tableview constraints**

a. Pin your tableview to superview from **top,left right**

b. Set **height** constraints of tableview.

[image]

c. Make outlet of height constraints for tableview so that we can alter value on runtime.
[image]

**2. Manage Cell constraints**

a. Pin your cell contents to superview from **top,left, right,bottom**
[image]
**3. manage tableview constraints on runtime**

a. set height constraints of tableview view to content size of table view from cell for tow at index path.

```
self.tableHeight.constant = self.locationTableView.contentSize.height
```

**Full controller Code.**

```
//  Controller.swift
//  Copyright © 2017 dip. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit


class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    //1:
    //Outlet of tableview Height constraints
    @IBOutlet weak var tableHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet var locationTableView: UITableView!

    let locationArray = ["Current Location", "Where to"]
    let picArray = ["currentPic.png", "whereTo.png"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationTableView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController1: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return locationArray.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GetLocation", for: indexPath)

        let location = locationArray[indexPath.row]
        let pic = picArray[indexPath.row]
        print(location)
        if let locationCell = cell as? GetLocationTableViewCell {
            locationCell.locationTitle.text = location
            locationCell.iconImage.image = pic
        }

        //2. set tableivew view height to content Height
        self.tableHeight.constant = self.locationTableView.contentSize.height


        return cell

    }
}
```

**Out Put**

[image]